# Subset does not work when done within cor.test in R

Tags: r, subset, correlation

I have a df with 3 columns:

- column_1: numeric
- column_2: numeric
- column_3: factor variable with two groups, A and B

I want to compute a Spearman's correlation test between columns 1 and 2, but only between groups (so the correlation is computed only between observations of columns 1 and 2 which match group A, the same applying to group B).
So I'm using these lines of code:

```
cor.test(df$column_1, df$column_2, alternative = ("two.sided"), 
     subset(df, column_3==c("group_A")),
     data = df, method = c("spearm"))
cor.test(df$column_1, df$column_2, alternative = ("two.sided"), 
         subset(df, column_3==c("group_B")),
         data = df, method = c("spearm"))
```

Thing is, I get the same result in both tests, so I guess the subset function is not working, because if I previously subset the groups, like this:

```
x <- subset(df, column_3==c("group_A"))
y <- subset(df, column_3==c("group_B"))
```

And then run `cor.test` on x and y separately, I get different results. Does anybody know what's going on?

PS: I get the following warning, but I don't think it has to do with the issue I'm asking about:

```
Warning message:
"In cor.test.default(cor_itir$Nart, cor_itir$Medida, alternative = "two.sided",  :cannot compute exact p-value with ties"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things a bit, by using `df$...` extractors and specifying `data=` and using `subset()` as a standalone function. You can get the same results I believe using something like:

```
# here's some example data with different correlations between each group
df <- data.frame(column_1=1:10,column_2=c(1:5,6,4,3,11,9),column_3=rep(c("a","b"),each=5))
```

Then just specify your forumula, your `data=` and your `subset=` inline:

```
cor.test(~ column_1 + column_2, alternative="two.sided", data=df, subset=(column_3=="a"))

cor.test(~ column_1 + column_2, alternative="two.sided", data=df, subset=(column_3=="b"))
```

Or all in one go using `by`

```
by(df, df$column_3, FUN = function(x) cor.test(~ column_1 + column_2, data = x))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Oh, I'd appreciate if you'd upvote my answer if you think it is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `with` and `subset`:

```
with(subset(df, column_3==c("group_A")),
     cor.test(column_1, column_2, alternative = ("two.sided"), 
     method = c("spearm")))

with(subset(df, column_3==c("group_B")),
     cor.test(column_1, column_2, alternative = ("two.sided"), 
              method = c("spearm")))
```

Edit

Adding data

```
df <- data.frame(column_1=1:10,column_2=c(1:5,6,4,3,11,9),column_3=rep(c("group_A","group_B"),each=5))

> with(subset(df, column_3==c("group_A")),
+      cor.test(column_1, column_2, alternative = ("two.sided"), 
+               method = c("spearman")))

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  column_1 and column_2
S = 4.4409e-15, p-value = 0.01667
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
rho 
  1 


> with(subset(df, column_3==c("group_B")),
+      cor.test(column_1, column_2, alternative = ("two.sided"), 
+               method = c("spearman")))

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  column_1 and column_2
S = 10, p-value = 0.45
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
rho 
0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting but that did not work. I still get the same output. The answer above worked, tho.

Comment: Take care, I did test my solution with the data in the other answer and it works!. Better that answer is doing  `pearson`  not `spearman` correlation

Comment: Oops, sorry about that! I'm doing something wrong here, I'll take a look into it, thank you!

Comment: Btw, I upvoted your answer but the score does not show because I don't have enough reputation