# 'x' must be a numeric vector despite being coerced to numeric

Tags: r

I want to compute the correlation for all the continuous features for each category in the `subtype` column (i.e., the last column). A total of 160 features should be selected.
In my code, the `subtype` column is coerced to numeric vector but I still get an error.

```
meth.clin$subtype <- as.numeric(factor(meth.clin$subtype))
cor.test(meth.clin[1:(length(meth.clin)-1)], meth.clin$subtype, method=c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))
```

Traceback:

```
Error in cor.test.default(meth.clin[1:(length(meth.clin) - 1)], meth.clin$subtype,  : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector
```

Data:

```
> dput(meth.clin[1:3,])
structure(list(cg06145336 = c(0.698400609291698, 0.790132158590308, 
0.550081662355945), cg06271190 = c(0.569616475152962, 0.457882228677053, 
0.450976691516467), cg07774251 = c(0.361663286004057, 0.522791070712472, 
0.573303889093363), cg03357952 = c(0.894450335807706, 0.851505819719192, 
0.790762216275151), cg06803853 = c(0.903375573519773, 0.5001145883731, 
0.688423092994612), cg09096824 = c(0.859059843307218, 0.738021999655486, 
0.590548915449314), cg04179953 = c(0.940601044067159, 0.537596430895065, 
0.932058544251989), cg03495084 = c(0.521922873745378, 0.120295281760689, 
0.191923990498812), cg07300846 = c(0.0702138966387671, 0.472352424198037, 
0.593854171886745), cg09221960 = c(0.738057576716229, 0.727940124898699, 
0.950431661654865), cg07160932 = c(0.144308943089431, 0.487917711991972, 
0.609003405893677), cg06239131 = c(0.964523395105969, 0.569710508599057, 
0.659275506357312), cg07512361 = c(0.313691440919966, 0.937831740976645, 
0.855020236181183), cg05613116 = c(0.0543364071436909, 0.35166041533254, 
0.530707519376331), cg01890845 = c(0.0627827129543844, 0.487718812703245, 
0.151359885608746), cg00111335 = c(0.971661960467931, 0.541259958845565, 
0.924031174031174), cg00425213 = c(0.49453190722269, 0.331156061244557, 
0.554841926212681), cg09187695 = c(0.652882820940969, 0.203590017349526, 
0.912106415221418), subtype = c(4, 1, 2)), row.names = c("TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01", 
"TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01", "TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How do I select features for each subtype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function, `cor.test`, requires two vectors of the same length, as described in the help documentation.  That means that you will compare two vectors of length = 160 to calculate your correlations.

If you want to do this test by subtype, you will use the subscript operator `[,]`.  Let's do two examples:

```
##this does cg06145336 versus cg06271190 for subtype = 1
cor.test(meth.clin$cg06145336[meth.clin$subtype==1], 
         meth.clin$cg06271190[meth.clin$subtype==1], 
                     method=c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))
```

This assumes that you have 3 or more subtypes that are named "1".

More than likely, you want something similar to this:

```
cor.test(~ cg06145336 + cg06271190, subset = (subtype==1), data = meth.clin)
```

This does one pairwise correlation test between cg06145336 and cg06271190.  To do all of your correlations, you're going to have to loop over all of your columns.

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710528/subset-does-not-work-when-done-within-cor-test-in-r).

And you will also have a bias problem because of Type I Error inflation with all of these p-values.  This will require you to do some type of alpha correction.  Use something such as `p.adjust`.